# MySQL - ошибка добавления данных в BIT(64)

Tags: mysql, bit

Запрос

```
INSERT INTO `table_name` (`phash`) 
VALUES 
( b'1111010110011110000010100111110100011101001100010101011101101010')
```

дает такой результат: 0111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
Если вставлять только 63 символа, то данные успешно добавляются с нулем в начале:
0111101011001111000001010011111010001110100110001010101110110101

С длиной 49, 36 работает нормально

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось, phpmyadmin отображает данные неверно, правильный запрос должен быть

```
SELECT BIN(phash+0) FROM table_name
```

Надеюсь, это может кому-нибудь быть полезным